# C# ObservableCollection Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, observablecollection

I've got such a class:

```
public class ProfileElementList : ObservableCollection<ProfileElement>
{
    public string BezierCurve { get; set; }
    public string BezierCurveLimit { get; set; }
}
```

It is serialized fine, except BezierCurve and BezierCurveLimit are not present
in XML.

What should I do to have them?

Comment: How are you serializing the data?

Comment: What are the definitions of `BezierCurve` and `BezierCurveLimit`?

Comment: Check parent class and make sure object are public.  Only public variables get serialized.  The child class object will be ignored if the parent(s) aren't public.

Comment: If you are using [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069099/when-a-class-is-inherited-from-list-xmlserializer-doesnt-serialize-other-att.

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660515/why-doesnt-this-class-property-serialize

Comment: I think you are right

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it like this:

```
    public class ProfileElementList
{
    public ProfileElementList() { }
    public ObservableCollection<ProfileElement> ProfileElements = new ObservableCollection<ProfileElement>();
    public BezierViewModel BezierCurve { get; set; }
    public BezierViewModel BezierCurveLimit { get; set; }
}
```

It works