# How to save DataGridView to XML using Linq without dataset

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dataset

I have a datagridview with 7 columns. This datagridview has no dataset connected to it. The User enters values ​​using the dataGridView.Rows.Add command...

There is the possibility to save these files to XML (Linq)?

Comment: There could be several ways of doing this. Is there any specific reason why you're not using dataset? I mean how are you going to connect to the database? You can use other technologies such as EF but it really depends on what you really want to achieve. Can you give some more details on this?

Comment: There is no connection to the database is just a grid with columns. I do not get it and an appropriate component to perform this task.

Comment: Are you using WPF or winforms? In WPF you can always bind your datagrid to an observablecollection then serialize it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633398/xmlserialize-an-observablecollection

Comment: i am using winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", 25 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mary", 26 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Bill", 27 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Beth", 28 });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            //reverse
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("NewTable");
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in  dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                dt2.Columns.Add(column.Name, column.ValueType);
            }
            //don't save last row of dattagridview which is the blank editable row
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
                DataRow newRow = dt2.Rows.Add();
                for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
                {
                    newRow[j] = row.Cells[j].Value;
                }
            }

            dt2.WriteXml(FILENAME, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
        }
    }
}
```

a datagridview from a datatable.  Then did reverse and created datatable from DGV and saved to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution:

```
void SaveData() {
        XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("Grid"));

        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        xmlDocument.Root.Add(
            new XElement("Grid",
                new XAttribute("xxx1", row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()),
                new XAttribute("xxx2", row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()),
                new XAttribute("xxx3", row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()),
                new XAttribute("xxx4", row.Cells[3].Value.ToString()),
                new XAttribute("xxx5", row.Cells[4].Value.ToString()),
                new XAttribute("xxx6", row.Cells[5].Value.ToString()),
                new XAttribute("xxx7", row.Cells[6].Value.ToString())));
        xmlDocument.Save("@Path");
    }

    void LoadData() {
        try {
            XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("@Path");

            foreach(XElement el in xmlDocument.Root.Elements()) {
                switch(el.Name.LocalName) {
                    case "Grid":
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(el.Attribute("xxx1").Value,el.Attribute("xxx2").Value,
                            el.Attribute("xxx3").Value,el.Attribute("xxx4").Value,el.Attribute("xxx5").Value,
                            el.Attribute("xxx6").Value,el.Attribute("xxx7").Value);
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```